# Emacs not waiting for user interactive input

Tags: emacs, ide

Good Morning, I am learning c++ and using emacs as IDE, the question is: if I write a simple program which requires user  iteraction (cin >> age ;) but emacs does not wait for the user and jumps to the next instruction. please any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can get user input with <kbd>M-x</kbd>
`compile`. You could use a Makefile with input redirection though, but
it may be not what you want.

Otherwise, you can launch a terminal inside Emacs for that.
Firstly,

```
(require 'dired-x)
```

This enables <kbd>C-x C-j</kbd> that opens a `dired` buffer
with the directory based on your current buffer. This means
that it would open the directory with your executable.

Next, I like to bind some easy key to open a terminal.

```lisp
(require 'dired-x)

(defun my-dired-hook ()
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "`") 'my-term))

(defun my-term ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/bin/bash"))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-dired-hook)
```

Once you're in a terminal, you're all set.  It is possible to launch a
terminal with some custom code without the `dired` bypass, but
I think that this approach is more flexible, since you can navigate
your `dired` buffer before opening the terminal.

Comment: (C-u M-x compile) will compile in comint mode which allows user input